# Jogo de JO KEN PO dando errado

Tags: python-3.x, if, random

Tô tentando fazer um jogo de jokenpo mas está dando errado.

```py
from random import choice
from time import sleep
print('[1]PAPEL\n'
      '[2]TESOURA\n'
      '[3]PEDRA')
escolha = input('Qual a sua escolha? ')
print('JO')
sleep(1)
print('KEN')
sleep(1)
print('PÔ')
lista = [1,2,3] #1(PAPEL),2(TESOURA),3(PEDRA)
pc_escolha = choice(lista)
if escolha == 1 and pc_escolha == 3 or escolha == 3 and pc_escolha == 2 or escolha == 2 and pc_escolha == 1:
    print('-*'*20)
    print('VOCÊ JOGOU {} E O COMPUTADOR JOGOU {}\n'
          'VOCE VENCEU'.format(escolha,pc_escolha))
    print('-*'*20)
elif escolha == pc_escolha:
    print('-*' * 20)
    print('VOCÊ JOGOU {} E O COMPUTADOR JOGOU {}\n'
          'EMPATE'.format(escolha, pc_escolha))
    print('-*' * 20)
elif pc_escolha == 1 and escolha == 3 or pc_escolha == 3 and escolha == 2 or pc_escolha == 2 and escolha == 1:
    print('-*' * 20)
    print('VOCÊ JOGOU {} E O COMPUTADOR JOGOU {}\n'
          'O COMPUTADOR VENCEU'.format(escolha, pc_escolha))
    print('-*' * 20)
```

Comment: O que está dando errado? Em qual linha a problema? o que deveria fazer e o que faz?

Comment: vc deve usar ( ) para separar as condições do if onde tem relação entre si, (a and b) or ( b and c) or (c and d)

Comment: Simplesmente não aparece saída. Era pra aparecer os conteúdos contidos dentro das estruturas de repetição.

Comment: @EltonNunes, Não funcionou

Comment: ok, olhei rapido por cima, vc esta comparando inteiro no if, mas input returna str, vc dve fazer a conversão int(input())

Comment: Exatamente isso que o Elton disse, apaguei a minha resposta pois não tinha visto que o amigo já tinha respondido nos comentários.

Comment: Não tinha percebido esse erro bobo. Esses erros são os piores pois o sistema não te avisa. Agradeço.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

analisando seu código encontrei uma solução simples e rápida.

A entidade escolha está recebendo uma string, sugiro adicionar uma cast tipo inteira para realizar a conversão. 
escolha = int (escolha)

[image: #conversão de valores em cast]

resultado:

[image: teste do codigo]